# LINQ, Join, Group By and SUM

Tags: vb.net, linq

In this VB.NET query, how can I get access to the fields in the new statement?

```vb
Dim query =
    From t1 In tbl1
    Join t2 In tbl2 On t1.CAMPAIGNID Equals t2.CAMPAIGNID
    Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
    Select New With {
     .id = CAMPAIGNID,
     .CALLS = Group.Sum(Function(a) t2.CALLS),
     .count = Group.Count(Function(a) t1.TERMCD = "Refused")
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe there's an easier way!

Comment: Joining two datatables on campaignid. One table has CALLS we want to sum for the whole campaignid. One has refusals we are counting in the other table. So we group by campaignid. But we need to access those fields to do our number crunching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the fields via the passed in parameter `a`. The parameter `a` is of the anonymous type you created via `New With {...}`

[image]

```vb
Dim query =
    From t1 In tbl1
    Join t2 In tbl2 On t1.CAMPAIGNID Equals t2.CAMPAIGNID
    Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
    Select New With {
        .id = CAMPAIGNID,
        .CALLS = Group.Sum(Function(a) a.t2.CALLS),
        .count = Group.Count(Function(a) a.t1.TERMCD = "Refused")
    }
```

Comment: OMG I am so sorry. That was so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Something is wrong though. CALLS and count come up with these obscenely huge numbers I know can't be right. I will examine more when I get home tonight.

Comment: @KJM Is there only one `tbl1` and one `tbl2` with the same CAMPAIGNID? Or are there potentially multiple on both sides?

Comment: Hey djv I found the problem. It works fine, doing the count if only one table. But adding the joined table (t2) is causing the number to inflate for CALLS and TERMCD. I think I need to find a way to only count the rows in the first table. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @KJM what about my last question. Are there multiple matches on either side?

Comment: Yes each campaignid has multiple corresponding records in t2