# LINQ, Join, GroupBy and Count

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have this vb.net LINQ query. Without the join the count and SUM worked perfectly on each. But with the join the count and SUM arent working properly due to the multiple CAMPAIGNID values. I suspect I need another group by statement in there but I am not entirely sure how to do that. IF you could help that would be great.

```
Dim query =
    From t1 In tbl1
    Join t2 In tbl2 On t1.CAMPAIGNID Equals t2.CAMPAIGNID
    Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
    Select New With {
        .id = CAMPAIGNID,
        .CALLS = Group.Sum(Function(a) a.t2.CALLS),
        .count = Group.Count(Function(a) a.t1.TERMCD = "Refused")
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `.id = t1.CAMPAIGNID`?

Comment: For background, this is a continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60284615/832052)

Comment: It gave me a scope error.

Comment: @KJM I'm going to post some code with data as an answer, can you give me some feedback as to if it is accurate?

Comment: Sure but will be after work. Thank u!

Comment: "It gave me a scope error" If I was your intended recipient, I didn't receive an inbox notification. To ensure your intended recipient receives a notification, you'll want to @mention him specifically if there is more than one participant in the thread. Also, the quality of your question can be improved. "It doesn't work" is very vague, and it doesn't help us understand your intent. I misunderstood your question, which is why I entered the (now-shown-to-be) irrelevant comment. Details, details, details... they're key to a good Q&A experience here on SO.

Comment: My apologies. I was in a hurry before work. I meant to say that the t1 reference was considered "out of scope" in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an example which seems to be working properly.

```vb
Public Class T1
    Public Property CAMPAIGNID As Integer
    Public Property TERMCD As String
End Class

Public Class T2
    Public Property CAMPAIGNID As Integer
    Public Property CALLS As Integer
End Class
```

```vb
Dim tbl1 As New List(Of T1) From {
    New T1 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 1, .TERMCD = "Refused"},
    New T1 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 1, .TERMCD = "Accepted"},
    New T1 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 2, .TERMCD = "Refused"},
    New T1 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 2, .TERMCD = "Accepted"},
    New T1 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 3, .TERMCD = "Refused"},
    New T1 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 3, .TERMCD = "Accepted"}
}
Dim tbl2 As New List(Of T2) From {
    New T2 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 1, .CALLS = 2},
    New T2 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 1, .CALLS = 4},
    New T2 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 2, .CALLS = 8},
    New T2 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 2, .CALLS = 16},
    New T2 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 3, .CALLS = 32},
    New T2 With {.CAMPAIGNID = 3, .CALLS = 64}
}

Dim query =
    From t1 In tbl1
    Join t2 In tbl2 On t1.CAMPAIGNID Equals t2.CAMPAIGNID
    Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
    Select New With {
        .id = CAMPAIGNID,
        .CALLS = Group.Sum(Function(a) a.t2.CALLS),
        .count = Group.Count(Function(a) a.t1.TERMCD = "Refused")
    }

For Each q In query
    Console.WriteLine($"ID:{q.id}, CALLS:{q.CALLS}, COUNT:{q.count}")
Next
```

> ID:1, CALLS:12, COUNT:2
>   ID:2, CALLS:48, COUNT:2
>   ID:3, CALLS:192, COUNT:2

In the case of ID 3, the CALLS sum of 192 is correct because the sum has no constraint of `TERMCD = "Refused"`, so it counts all. And the count of 2 is accurate because has a constraint where `TERMCD = "Refused"`.

Just looking at the group, without aggregation, let's see what is returned

```vb
Dim query =
    From t1 In tbl1
    Join t2 In tbl2 On t1.CAMPAIGNID Equals t2.CAMPAIGNID
    Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group

For Each q In query
    Console.WriteLine($"ID:{q.CAMPAIGNID}")
    For Each g In q.Group
        Console.WriteLine($"t1.CAMPAIGNID:{g.t1.CAMPAIGNID}, t1.TERMCD:{g.t1.TERMCD}, t2.CAMPAIGNID:{g.t2.CAMPAIGNID}, t2.CALLS:{g.t2.CALLS}")
    Next
Next
```

> ID:1
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:1, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:1, t2.CALLS:2
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:1, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:1, t2.CALLS:4
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:1, t1.TERMCD:Accepted, t2.CAMPAIGNID:1, t2.CALLS:2
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:1, t1.TERMCD:Accepted, t2.CAMPAIGNID:1, t2.CALLS:4
>   ID:2
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:2, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:2, t2.CALLS:8
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:2, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:2, t2.CALLS:16
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:2, t1.TERMCD:Accepted, t2.CAMPAIGNID:2, t2.CALLS:8
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:2, t1.TERMCD:Accepted, t2.CAMPAIGNID:2, t2.CALLS:16
>   ID:3
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:32
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:64
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Accepted, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:32
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Accepted, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:64

Now it should be clear why you see what you see.

Sum with no constraint:

> t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:32
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:64
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Accepted, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:32
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Accepted, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:64

Count where `a.t1.TERMCD = "Refused"`

> t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:32
>   t1.CAMPAIGNID:3, t1.TERMCD:Refused, t2.CAMPAIGNID:3, t2.CALLS:64

I'm not sure what you *want* to see, but this should at least show you that your output is accurate.

Now that we got that out of the way, your SQL query is below

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A.CAMPAIGNID
              , RFJOIN.RF
              , CCJOIN.CC
              , CALLSJOIN.CALLS
              , CALLSJOIN.CALLS / RFJOIN.RF as Calculated 
FROM tbl1 A 
inner join (SELECT CAMPAIGNID
                 , count() as RF 
            FROM tbl1 
            WHERE TERMCD='Refused' 
            GROUP by CAMPAIGNID) RFJOIN on RFJOIN.CAMPAIGNID = a.CAMPAIGNID 
inner join (SELECT CAMPAIGNID
                 , count() as CC 
            FROM tbl1 
            WHERE TERMCD LIKE '%Con%' 
            GROUP by CAMPAIGNID) CCJOIN on CCJOIN.CAMPAIGNID = a.CAMPAIGNID 
inner join (SELECT CAMPAIGNID
                 , SUM(CALLS) as CALLS 
            FROM tbl2 
            GROUP by CAMPAIGNID) CALLSJOIN on CALLSJOIN.CAMPAIGNID = a.CAMPAIGNID
```

I would break it into the subqueries then join them together. You can almost copy the SQL syntax this way

```vb
Dim RFJ = From t1 In tbl1
          Where t1.TERMCD = "Refused"
          Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
          Select New With {CAMPAIGNID, .RF = Group.Count()}
Dim CCJ = From t1 In tbl1
          Where t1.TERMCD.Contains("Con")
          Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
          Select New With {CAMPAIGNID, .CC = Group.Count()}
Dim CAJ = From t2 In tbl2
          Group By t2.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
          Select New With {CAMPAIGNID, .CALLS = Group.Count()}
Dim query = From A In tbl1
            Join RFJOIN In RFJ On RFJOIN.CAMPAIGNID Equals A.CAMPAIGNID
            Join CCJOIN In CCJ On CCJOIN.CAMPAIGNID Equals A.CAMPAIGNID
            Join CALLSJOIN In CAJ On CALLSJOIN.CAMPAIGNID Equals A.CAMPAIGNID
            Select New With {A.CAMPAIGNID, RFJOIN.RF, CCJOIN.CC, CALLSJOIN.CALLS, .Calculated = CALLSJOIN.CALLS / RFJOIN.RF}
Dim queryDistinct = query.Distinct()

' or in one big ugly query :)

Dim fullQuery = (From A In tbl1
                 Join RFJOIN In From t1 In tbl1
                                Where t1.TERMCD = "Refused"
                                Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
                                Select New With {CAMPAIGNID, .RF = Group.Count()} On RFJOIN.CAMPAIGNID Equals A.CAMPAIGNID
                 Join CCJOIN In From t1 In tbl1
                                Where t1.TERMCD.Contains("Con")
                                Group By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
                                Select New With {CAMPAIGNID, .CC = Group.Count()} On CCJOIN.CAMPAIGNID Equals A.CAMPAIGNID
                 Join CALLSJOIN In From t2 In tbl2
                                   Group By t2.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
                                   Select New With {CAMPAIGNID, .CALLS = Group.Count()} On CALLSJOIN.CAMPAIGNID Equals A.CAMPAIGNID
                 Select New With {A.CAMPAIGNID, RFJOIN.RF, CCJOIN.CC, CALLSJOIN.CALLS, .Calculated = CALLSJOIN.CALLS / RFJOIN.RF}).Distinct()
```

Comment: Ok you are exactly right @djv . Hopefully I at least did the name right. This is exactly right with how I worded the query. The problem is that of course it actually isn't what I am looking for. In my original SQL query I did it like this: (which was right)

Comment: @KJM ha, yeah but when you comment on an answer, the answer's author *always* gets a notification :). So in my example, what do you expect the sum and count to be?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT A.CAMPAIGNID, RFJOIN.RF, CCJOIN.CC, CALLSJOIN.CALLS, CALLSJOIN.CALLS / RFJOIN.RF as Calculated
FROM tbl1 A 
 
inner join (SELECT CAMPAIGNID,count(*) as RF FROM tbl1 WHERE TERMCD='Refused' GROUP by CAMPAIGNID) RFJOIN on RFJOIN.CAMPAIGNID = a.CAMPAIGNID
inner join (SELECT CAMPAIGNID,count(*) as CC FROM tbl1 WHERE TERMCD LIKE '%Con%' GROUP by CAMPAIGNID) CCJOIN on CCJOIN.CAMPAIGNID = a.CAMPAIGNID
inner join (SELECT CAMPAIGNID,SUM(CALLS) as CALLS FROM tbl2 GROUP by CAMPAIGNID) CALLSJOIN on CALLSJOIN.CAMPAIGNID = a.CAMPAIGNID

Comment: I was hoping to replicate that in LINQ and I thought I was close. So I started trying to use Group Join but it wasn't working either. So I continue to struggle with this. Btw thank you for all your help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @KJM I mean in my example how is my code wrong? I don't have your data, which is why I created my own. Your query is nothing like your LINQ. You could probably duplicate it into LINQ but I see no attempt at that...

Comment: Your code is not wrong at all. I am wrong with my LINQ query. I am just starting with it so I am trying to duplicate it and the syntax is throwing me. Your example was excellent at pointing out that I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: @KJM I would take the subqueries and assign them to variables. Then join them together.

Comment: If I found the answer of how to write the query do I post it here? Or at this point is nobody really watching or caring....

Comment: @KJM I cared enough to make this big answer. I'd be interested in seeing your query. Is it close to mine? (You can create an answer to your own question if no existing answer came close enough / you solved it on your own without help)

Comment: fair enough and yes you did. I just hesitated and asked cause every time I do something on here someone always yells at me for something lol.... So I will click the answer button and do this...

Comment: @KJM yup, the company is aware of that and is trying to make this place more welcome to newcomers / occasional visitors. Hope you stick around :)

Answer (score 0):

It truly is a case of me making it WAY more complicated then it was and not knowing enough to ask the right questions. I wanted to mimic the subquery concept in TSQL but I didn't explain it well. What threw me was the LINQ syntax which seems to always be my downfall with LINQ. I know what I wanted to do I just didn't know how to do it the LINQ way. Thanks to you all who have helped especially @djv.

```
Dim query =
    From t1 In tbl1 Group t1 By t1.CAMPAIGNID Into grp = Group
    Join t2 In (From p In tbl2 Group p By p.CAMPAIGNID Into g = Group
                Select New With {
                              .CAMPAIGNID = CAMPAIGNID,
                              .CALLS = CType(g.Sum(Function(d) d.CALLS), Integer?).GetValueOrDefault(0),
                   })
                    On CAMPAIGNID Equals t2.CAMPAIGNID
    Select New With {
        .CampaignID = CAMPAIGNID,
        .RF = CType(grp.Count(Function(b) b.TERMCD = "Refused"), Integer?).GetValueOrDefault(0),        
        .CALLS = t2.CALLS
        }
```